# Convert png/jpg/gif to ico

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, imagelist

I have multiple images some of them are png some of them jpg and gif and i want to display them in a listview as thumbails TImageList supports only icons how can i convert them to be able to insert them in TImageList.

I am using Delphi XE

Comment: this sounds like yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/961542/920384

Comment: IcoFX can create and import images into ICO files.

Comment: Standard `TImageList` also supports bitmaps.

Comment: ImageList does **not** require icons, it will load .bmp files just fine.  And for that the linked question should fix your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load Jpg/Gif/Bitmap and convert to Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959160/load-jpg-gif-bitmap-and-convert-to-bitmap)

Comment: Since D2009 TImageList also supports PNG directly.

Comment: @Johan, converting to BMP and ICO are two different things when you go into details. I would not see this as a duplicate even if some of the answers and comments may overlap.

Comment: If you have a lot of images then image list is liable to be limiting. The image list stores a single bitmap with all images stitched together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To specifically answer the question, also to take simple resizing into account (for thumbnails), some example code:

```
var
  Img: TImage;
  BmImg: TBitmap;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  BmpMask: TBitmap;
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  Ico: TIcon;
begin
  Img := TImage.Create(nil);
  Img.Picture.LoadFromFile(...

  BmImg := TBitmap.Create;
  BmImg.Assign(Img.Picture.Graphic);
  Img.Free;

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.SetSize(ImageList1.Width, ImageList1.Height);
  SetStretchBltMode(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, HALFTONE);
  StretchBlt(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height,
              BmImg.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BmImg.Width, BmImg.Height, SRCCOPY);
  BmImg.Free;

  BmpMask := TBitmap.Create;
  BmpMask.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  BmpMask.SetSize(Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);

  FillChar(IconInfo, SizeOf(IconInfo), 0);
  IconInfo.fIcon := True;
  IconInfo.hbmMask := BmpMask.Handle;
  IconInfo.hbmColor := Bmp.Handle;

  Ico := TIcon.Create;
  Ico.Handle := CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);

  ImageList1.AddIcon(Ico);

  Bmp.Free;
  BmpMask.Free;
  Ico.Free;  // calls DestroyIcon
end;
```

or, without creating an icon:

```
var
  Img: TImage;
  BmImg: TBitmap;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Img := TImage.Create(nil);
  Img.Picture.LoadFromFile(..

  BmImg := TBitmap.Create;
  BmImg.Assign(Img.Picture.Graphic);
  Img.Free;

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.SetSize(ImageList1.Width, ImageList1.Height);
  SetStretchBltMode(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, HALFTONE);
  StretchBlt(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height,
              BmImg.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BmImg.Width, BmImg.Height, SRCCOPY);
  BmImg.Free;

  ImageList1.AddMasked(Bmp, clNone);

  Bmp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I often get the exception : Out of system resources why do you think is that ?

Comment: @opc0de, the above samples work with a few gdi handles, but as far as I can see there should be no leak. But you would of course want to modify the code to guarantee freeing vcl objects, using try finally blocks. I can't really say..

Comment: I used a jpeg image to dump the thumbnail on disk after i replaced the jpeg with a bmp i stopped getting that nasty error. There wasn't no leak but i don't know...