# TBitmap32.LoadFromStream() Auto-Recognize Image Format

Tags: delphi, image-formats, graphics32

I'm using Delphi XE2 (Update 3) and GR32.  I am unable to use `TBitmap32.LoadFromStream()` to load the image data.  It raises the following exception:

```
Project MyApp.exe raised exception class EInvalidGraphic with message 'Bitmap image is not valid'.
```

### Code

```
uses GR32, GifImg, PngImage, Vcl.Graphics;

var
  pic: TBitmap32;
  bs: TBytesStream;
begin
  bs := TBytesStream.Create(TClientDataSet(cds).FieldByName('filedata').AsBytes);
  try
    pic := TBitmap32.Create;
    try
//      bs.SaveToFile('c:\delme.png');
//      pic.LoadFromFile('c:\delme.png');
      pic.LoadFromStream(bs); // <- EInvalidGraphic exception
      // do something with 'pic'
    finally
      FreeAndNil(pic);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(bs);
  end;
end;
```

### Workaround(s)

If I comment the `LoadFromStream()` code and uncomment the prior two lines, it works -- so it is able to determine the image format when loading it from a file.  In this example, `bs` contains a valid PNG image.  However, sometimes it may be a GIF, JPG, BMP or another graphic format.

I also know that I can use an intermediate object (e.g., `TPNGImage`, `TJPEGImage`, etc.), load the image data using `LoadFromStream()` into the intermediate object, and then `Assign()` it to the `TBitmap32`.  However, it would be better if `TBitmap32` could handle any type of image without an intermediate object, which I thought it could...

### Question

Does anyone know how to use `TBitmap32.LoadFromStream()` to load the image and have it auto-recognize the image format **without** saving the image to the HDD (even temporarily), or using an intermediate object?

Comment: Try Vampyrу Imaging. The project aims at combining speed of Graphics32 and format flexibility of GraphicEx. Dunno how much they succed though, but there were warm reports from their users.

Comment: @Arioch'The - I'll look at.  Thanks.  FYI - Here's the SourceForge link: http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code for `LoadFromFile`:

```
procedure TCustomBitmap32.LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  Header: TBmpHeader;
  P: TPicture;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead);
  try
    FileStream.ReadBuffer(Header, SizeOf(TBmpHeader));

    // Check for Windows bitmap magic bytes...
    if Header.bfType = $4D42 then
    begin
      // if it is, use our stream read method...
      FileStream.Seek(-SizeOf(TBmpHeader), soFromCurrent);
      LoadFromStream(FileStream);
      Exit;
    end
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;

  // if we got here, use the fallback approach via TPicture...
  P := TPicture.Create;
  try
    P.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Assign(P);
  finally
    P.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, the code checks to see if the file is a Windows bitmap. If so then it loads it directly by calling `LoadFromStream`.

If not then it loads into a `TPicture` and then assigns to this instance.

The point is that `LoadFromStream` only understands Windows bitmaps. It does not understand any other file format. And you are trying to load a PNG. So, there's no way to do what you need without using an intermediate object.

The solution for you is to:

1. Instantiate a `TPNGImage` object.
2. Call `LoadFromStream` on that instance.
3. Call `Assign` on the `TBitmap32` instance passing the `TPNGImage` instance.

Comment: It's good to know that `LoadFromStream` is specific to the instantiated object type -- that it **cannot** auto-detect the type of image in the data steam.  Thanks David.

Comment: Just found this too, which lists a few different ways to accomplish this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959160/load-jpg-gif-bitmap-and-convert-to-bitmap

Comment: The main point is that you need an intermediate object because `TBitmap32` cannot decode PNG

Answer (score 6):

Delphi XE2 includes a class in `Vcl.Graphics` called `TWICImage` that handles images supported by the [*Windows Imaging Component*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including **BMP, GIF, ICO, JPEG, PNG, TIF and Windows Media Photo**.  This means you can load any of the supported image types directly from a stream and it will automatically detect the image type and load it.  Then the loaded image can be assigned to the `TBitmap32` component (or a `TImage` or a `TImage32`, etc.).

```
uses GR32, Vcl.Graphics;

var
  pic: TBitmap32;
  wic: TWICImage;
  bs: TBytesStream;
begin
  bs := TBytesStream.Create(TClientDataSet(cds).FieldByName('filedata').AsBytes);
  try
    pic := TBitmap32.Create;
    try
      wic := TWICImage.Create;
      try
        bs.Position := 0;
        wic.LoadFromStream(bs);
        pic.Assign(wic);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(wic);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(pic);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(bs);
  end;
end;
```

It works without adding `PNGImage`, `GIFImg`, or `JPEG` to your `uses` statement.