# Jpeg to Bmp conversion takes unreasonable amount of time

Tags: delphi

I have this function that takes 4.2 seconds to convert a jpg to bmp.
Why it takes so long? Can I make if faster?
IrfanView loads and converts the file in only a fraction of that time.

I thought that is spends most of the time in JPG.LoadFromFile. But when I measured the time I was surprised to see it spends most of the time in BMP.Assing(JPG).

```
function ConvertJPG2BMP(CONST FileName: string): TBitmap;
VAR JPG: TJpegImage;
begin
 Result:= NIL;
 JPG:= TJpegImage.Create;
 TRY
   JPG.LoadFromFile(FileName);
   if  (JPG.Width > 0) AND (JPG.Width  < 32768)
   AND (JPG.Height> 0) AND (JPG.Height < 32768) then
    begin
      Result:= TBitmap.Create;
      TRY
        Result.HandleType:= bmDIB;

        // Fuji_FinePix_F550.JPG    [3200x1800] [1.44MB] 
        Result.Assign(JPG);  <--- 4 seconds!!
      EXCEPT
        FreeAndNil(Result);
      END;
    end;
 FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(JPG);
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Actual decompression occurs in the assign function. That's why its slow.

Comment: Since you are not showing your image anywhere in your application you could try to use `TBitmap` class from `FMX.Graphics` to load the image from JPG and then directly save it to BMP. Yes `FMX.Graphics.TBitmap` class can also be used in VCL application.

Comment: there is this open source library for imaging. I see some ASM code in the JPG unit. I haven't tested yet: https://sourceforge.net/p/imaginglib/code/ci/default/tree/Source/ImagingJpeg.pas

Comment: TJpegImage.LoadFromFile does only minimal processing, but the actual, slow resource intensive conversion from JPG to BMP happens in TBitmap.Assign.
In some cases, you can call [TjpegImage.DIBNeeded](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.DIBNeeded) to pre-process the BMP copy before assigning it or drawing it.
Once a bitmap has been generated by TJPegImage object, the
assignment to another picture object is fast since the bitmap handle is
shared, the copy does not create a new instance of the bitmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I wanted to test the slightly older functions once, it is a good opportunity to do this now.

[The sources used are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959160/load-jpg-gif-bitmap-and-convert-to-bitmap)

These have been changed a bit in the code below.

**Somewhat adapted source code of OP's `function ConvertJPG2BMP()` (2512 : ms)**

[image]

```
function ConvertJPG2BMP(CONST FileName: string): TBitmap;
VAR
 JPG: TJpegImage;
begin
 Result:= NIL;
 JPG:= TJpegImage.Create;
 TRY
   JPG.LoadFromFile(FileName);
   if  (JPG.Width > 0) AND (JPG.Width  < 32768)
   AND (JPG.Height> 0) AND (JPG.Height < 32768) then
    begin
      Result:= TBitmap.Create;
      TRY
        Result.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
        Result.Width  := JPG.Width;
        Result.Height := JPG.Height;
        Result.HandleType:= bmDIB;
        // 2018-10-17 14.04.23.jpg    [2560x1920] [1.66MB]
        Result.Assign(JPG); 
        Result.SaveToFile('F:\ProgramFiles\Embarcadero\dtx\Projects\Bmp-DIB\JPG2BMP.bmp');
      EXCEPT
        FreeAndNil(Result);
      END;
    end;
 FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(JPG);
 end;
end;
```

---

**The source for the [TWICImage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage) usage (296 : ms)**

There is another class in `Vcl.Graphics?` called `TWICImage` that handles images supported by the Microsoft Imaging Component

Including BMP, GIF, ICO, JPEG, PNG, TIF and Windows Media Photo

---

[image]

```
procedure LoadImageFromStream(Stream: TStream; Image: TImage);
var
  wic: TWICImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Stream.Position := 0;
  wic := TWICImage.Create;
  try
    wic.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    Image.Picture.Assign(wic);
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      Bitmap.Width  := Image.Picture.Width;
      Bitmap.Height := Image.Picture.Height;
      Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Image.Picture.Graphic);
      Bitmap.SaveToFile('F:\ProgramFiles\Embarcadero\dtx\Projects\Bmp-DIB\TWICImage.bmp');
    finally
      Bitmap.Free;
    end;
  finally
    wic.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RenderImage(const Filename: string);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead);
  try
    LoadImageFromStream(fs, Form1.Image1);
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**GetTickCount for all tested routines.**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
MyDIB   : TBitmap;
loadStr : string;
XStart,Xend   : LongWord;
begin
loadStr := 'F:\ProgramFiles\Embarcadero\dtx\Projects\Bmp-DIB\2018-10-17 14.04.23.jpg';
XStart := GetTickCount;

if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0 then MyDIB := ConvertJPG2BMP(loadStr);// ConvertJPG2BMP()
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 1 then TestBmp(loadStr);
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 2 then RenderImage(loadStr);// TWICImage
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 3 then GetOleGraphic(loadStr);

Xend := GetTickCount;
Label1.Caption := IntToStr(xEnd-XStart) + ' : MS' ;

end;
```

**The generated images are identical to the file size only from the function `GetOleGraphic()` is a smaller file produced with a worse resolution?**

[here the source used for the **GetOleGraphic()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961542/1322642)

[image]

Comment: What about the time for TPicture? I guess is similar with the one for Jpg2Bmp. Right?

Comment: in "LoadImageFromStream" -> Is it possible to assign the wic directly to a BMP? so, we get rid of TImage

Comment: TPicture = 2356 ms : `"Is it possible to assign the wic directly to a BMP?"` -> You can try to improve it :-)

Comment: News: New versions of Delphi (Sydney and Alexandria) have improved supoort for WIC.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compact version of WIC image loader posted by moskito-x above.
Please VOTE HIS answer not mine. My answer here is only to provide the compact version and some details.

```
{-----------------------------------------------
  Uses TWICImage

  Advantages:  
      8+ times faster than Delphi's JPG function
      Works with: animated GIF, PNG, JPG
  
  Drawbacks: 
      Fails with JPEG2K
      No EXIF support
      Platform dependent
 -----------------------------------------------}

function LoadImageWic(CONST FileName: string): TBitmap;
VAR
   wic: TWICImage;
begin
  wic := TWICImage.Create;
  TRY
   wic.LoadFromFile(FileName);
   Result := TBitmap.Create;
   TRY
     Result.Assign(wic);
   EXCEPT
     FreeAndNil(Result);
   END;
  FINALLY
    FreeAndNil(wic);
  END;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks : fast, short and flush.

Comment: News: New versions of Delphi (Sydney and Alexandria) have improved supoort for WIC.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to decompress the jpeg using our [Open Source SynGDIPlus unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/20/GIF%2C-TIF%2C-PNG-and-JPG-pictures-TGraphic-read/write-via-GDI).

We found it much faster than the Delphi built-in jpeg.pas unit.

The latest revision [can be retrieved from github](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynGdiPlus.pas).

As an alternative, you may try to use our [fast Jpeg decoder using SSE2](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/18/Fast-JPEG-decoder-using-SSE/SSE2-version-1.1) but it doesn't handle all kind of Jpegs, and it is for Win32 only.

Comment: @Rigel SynGdiPlus (and the SSE2 decoder) are used on production for years to produce jpeg-oriented videos with great stability (in a multi-threaded server process) and much better performance than the standard jpeg.pas unit - so I guess something was wrong with your use

Comment: I tried it in the past, and it was not decoding properly some jpegs (I have found 4-5 files that were not decoded properly).